# How to specify the dimensions of a container as the total dimensions of its children in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using React Native `0.57.8` and React `16.7`. I have a container which contains many children. I want the container to take on the dimensions as the sum total of the dimensions of its children. How do I accomplish this?

```
<View style={[styles.container]}>
  <Text style={[styles.title]}>{title}</Text>
  <Text style={[styles.title]}>{title}</Text>
  <Text style={[styles.title]}>{title}</Text>
  <Text style={[styles.title]}>{title}</Text>
</View>
```

The dimensions of the `View` should be equal to the sum total of the dimensions of the `Text`s.

Comment: The dimensions of a View are determined automatically by the dimensions of its children if you don't provide any styles, so why would you want to specify it explicitly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dimensions of the `View` are auto taken, But for spacing you have to use the concept of `flex`.

Example:

```
<View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:"space-evenly",alignItems:"center"}}>
  <Text style={[styles.title]}>{title}</Text>
  <Text style={[styles.title]}>{title}</Text>
  <Text style={[styles.title]}>{title}</Text>
  <Text style={[styles.title]}>{title}</Text>
</View>
```